# How to store nested collection using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am working on Spring Boot+Hibernate project, in that I have an entity and I want to store nested collection of below type.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "data_stat",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="data_id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name="data_stat")
@Column(name="stat")
private List<Map<String,Object>> data;
```

When I run the application without any insert I am getting below exception
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map

I have changed @ElementCollection to @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class). In this case when I run the application without insert , I am not getting any error, but when I try to insert data I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String.

May I know how I should handle nested collection in hibernate?

Comment: An `ElementCollection` in JPA is for storing a Collection of a simple type. You'd have to create an intermediate entity with a field of type `Map<String,Object>` and refer to that

Comment: `private List<Map<String,Object>> data` JPA does not currently support such mappings. You'd need to map a simple list and do any transformation to a Map in memory.

Comment: JPA does support such a mapping (as I already proposed) when you have an AttributeConverter on the value of the map to convert the Object to something persistable ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.